# The DB does not populate with the data

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I ve created a table in Postgres and do a relation in java code :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "resources")
public class Resource {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "raport_id")
    private BigDecimal raportId;
    @Column(name = "reference_id")
    private String referenceId;
}
```

Also I created a repository

```
public class ResourcesRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void persist(BigDecimal raportId, String referenceId, String type) {
        Resource resource = new Resource();
        resource.setRaportSysId(raportId);
        resource.setReferenceId(referenceId);
        entityManager.persist(raport);
    }

    public void updateRaportId(BigDecimal raportId) {
        entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Resource r set r.raportId = :raportId ")
                .setParameter("raportId", raportId)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

I am passing the parameter raportId in dofferent location invoking the query like this:

```
ResourcesRepository.updateRaportId(raport.getId());
```

I do not have any errors but the table is not populated. Wonder what I am doing wrong? Should I use Insert INTO instead of update?

Comment: Do you really want to unconditionally update all resources to set their `raportId` to that value?!

Comment: Yes - for now. Later when I will populate new fields I will distinguish them. As fir now I just want to set raportId to every record

Answer (score 1):

make sure you commit your transaction after update/persist

Comment: When I invoked persist method I got an error :Unexpected Exception class: TransactionRolledbackLocalException: message: Error committing transaction: